# Python Elif statement not executing fourth condition

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, speech-recognition

I'm building a Desktop Assistant in python.

The if Condition and first two Elif conditions are working just file but when I try to call the fourth Elif contion, it automatically calls the third Elif condition no matter how I change my conditions.

I have tried replacing third Elif by fourth Elif, but still its executing the Elif at third position.

Here is my code ...... Problem exists in run() function

```
# region                                                                            Importing Modules
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes
import webbrowser
# endregion

gender=0
rate = 190
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[gender].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate)   
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[gender].id)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def tk_command():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        try:
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice, language="en-in")
            command=str(command)
            return command
        except Exception as e:
            speak("Didn't hear anything, try again.")
            tk_command()

def hotword():
    global gender
    command = tk_command()
    if 'jarvis' in command.lower():
        gender=1
        speak("Jarves, hey buddy. You're up.")
        gender=0
        speak('Well, I am here to assist')
        print (command)
        run()
    elif 'friday' in command.lower():
        gender=0
        speak("Hey Friday, it's your call")
        gender=1
        speak('Ok, how can I assist')
        print (command)
        run()

def anything_else():                                                #### Check if this works ####
    speak("Any other service I can do ?")
    command=tk_command()
    command.lower()
    if 'no' or 'nope' or 'nah' or 'na' in command:
        speak("Ok. Happy to help.")
        print(command)
        hotword()
    elif command == 'yes' or command == 'yeah' or command == 'yup':
            speak("Ok. Just ask me.")
            run()
    else:
        speak("Sure...")
        run(command, True)


def run(command=None, check=False):
    global rate
    # region                                                                        Taking command input
    if check == False:
        command = tk_command()
    command = command.lower()
    command = command.replace('friday', '')
    command = command.replace('Jarvis', '')
    # endregion

''' Functioning of various commands are describes below
     as multiple elif statements '''

if ('play' or 'search') and 'youtube' in command and 'google' not in command:   # Play or search on youtube
    song = command.replace('play', '')
    song = song.replace('youtube', '')
    song = song.replace('on', '')
    song = song.replace('for', '')
    speak('Playing.'+ song)
    pywhatkit.playonyt(song)

elif ('send' or 'message') and 'whatsapp' in command:                           # Sending a Whatsapp message
    if 'to' not in command:                 # Check if phone number is input
        speak('''Please say the command with a phone number or a contact name.
             To save a new contact say, Save... your phone number... 
                as... name of the recepient.''')
    else:                                   # Else Send the message
        command = command.replace('send', '')
        command = command.replace('whatsapp', '')
        command = command.replace('message', '')
        command = command.replace('to', '')
        command = command.replace('on', '')
        try:
            number = int(command.replace(' ',''))
            speak("Sure, what's the message.")
            message = tk_command()
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(f"+91{number}", message)
        except Exception as e:
            speak('Invalid number or contact, please try again.')
            print (command)
            run()

elif 'time' in command:                                                         # Asking what time is it
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    speak('Right now, its, '+ time)

elif 'search google for' or ('search' and 'on google') in command:              # Searches anything on google
    print('Google Search')
    command=command.replace('search google for', '')
    command=command.replace('search', '')
    command=command.replace('on google', '')
    command=command.replace(' ', '+')
    pywhatkit.search(command)
    
elif (('who' or 'what') and 'is') or 'wikipedia' in command:                    # Searches wikipedia for anything or anyone
    print(command)
    print('Wikipedia Search')
    lines = 1
    if 'explain' in command:
        lines = 3
        command = command.replace('explain', '')
    command = command.replace('who', '')
    command = command.replace('what', '')
    command = command.replace('is', '')
    info = pywhatkit.info(command, lines)
    rate -= 20
    speak(info)
    rate += 20

else:                                                                           # Exits the program
    speak('Exiting the program.')
    sys.exit()

anything_else()


hotword()
```

Comment: not sure if this is a problem only in the question or in your code. but the `if` ... `elif` ... are on the same indention level as your `def run()` so they are not part of that function

Comment: @derpirscher Sorry for the formatting, this happened while posting the question. If, elif and else statements are perfectly aligned inside def run() in my code editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions don't work in the way you think: `(('who' or 'what') and 'is') or 'wikipedia' in command:`  should be `((('who' in command) or ('what' in command)) and 'is' in command) or 'wikipedia' in command` and so on.
`(('who' or 'what') and 'is') or 'wikipedia'` is equivalent to `is` because of the way boolean operators are implemented in Python, so condition as you wrote it is equivalent to `'is' in command`.

See [Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html):

*Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to   `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value. Because `not` has to create a new value, it returns a boolean value regardless of the type of its argument (for example, `not 'foo'` produces `False` rather than `''`.)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it's working just fine now. And also I forgot to mention before that there is problem in def anything_else() .  In this function only if condition is working, not even else. Thanks in advance

Comment: And whenever def take_command() function encounters exception and runs def take_command again the this attribute error occurs. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'. But I can't exclude lower() because it's really needed

Comment: If I got you question correctly - you are missing `return` in `except Exception as e:`. So, it  runs `tk_command` again but doesn't return the result, i.e. returns `None`

Comment: @SamratGupta The conditions in `anything_else()` have the same problem as in `run()`. `if 'no' or 'nope' or 'nah' or 'na' in command` should be `if 'no' in command or 'nope' in command or 'nah' in command or 'na' in command`.  BTW you don't need to check for both `no`  and `nope` because, if `no` is not contained in command, `nope` can't be. Same for `na` and `nah`

Comment: Thankyou so much, it relly solved my problem.